# Connection refused for container in multicontainer Docker environment on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy a tomcat container as part of a multicontainer environment on Elastic beanstalk.

Everything works fine locally with

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:9.0
```

When opening `http://localhost:8888/` in the browser, the HTTP status 404 with footer `Apache Tomcat/9.0.34` appears which is expected because I'm using the official image that doesn't come with any services (that I'm aware of).

[image]

Now I want to use this container as access point in a cluster on elastic beanstalk.

I select `Create Application` and supply my Dockerrun.aws.json¹:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "vanilla-tomcat",
      "image": "tomcat:9.0",
      "essential": "true",
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8888,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": []
    }
  ]
}
```

*Health* is green, there are no errors, but when I call the address, e.g.
with `curl http://vanillatomcat-env.eba-abc.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/` I get
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to vanillatomcat-env.eba-xy.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com port 80: Connection refused`
with `curl http://vanillatomcat-env.eba-abc.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:8888` I get `Connection timed out`.

The security group has one inbound rule:

```
Type Protocol Port range Source     Description - optional
HTTP TCP      80         0.0.0.0/0  -
```

What do I need to configure to be able to access my container?

¹I'm purposefully only supplying one container to keep things simple but other environments are not a solution, it has to be a multicontainer environment!

**Progress**

1. On (my understanding of a) suggestion by Marcin I set `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:Port` to different values under *Configuration -> Software -> Environment properties*:

[image]

But this did not change anything for calling either `address` or `address:1234`

2. I've further tried the same thing with flask where the image is `poroko/flask-demo-app` and the `containerPort` is 5000. Again it works locally(`docker run -it --rm -p 8888:5000 poroko/flask-demo-app`), but not on elastic beanstalk, so I assume that this problem is not specific to tomcat but due to the setup.

Comment: Looking at what I have in my eb ecs docker, I think you have to adjust the port using [aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess). You can also do this through console first to check if it helps, before adding it to `.ebextensions` file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `"hostPort": 80` solved it for me.